# How to get the url address from upper function in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

In my Scrapy `spider.py`, see the last two rows. I want to get the URL address from `url1` in `parse()`. How to code?

```
class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):    
     name = "sh2"

     def __init__(self, category=None, *args, **kwargs):
          # super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.start_urls = ['http://esf.suzhou.fang.com/housing/__1_0_0_0_1_0_0/',]      

     def parse(self, response):          
          num = response.xpath('//*[@id="pxBox"]/p/b/text()').extract()[0]
          if int(num) >2000:
               urls = response.xpath('//*[@id="houselist_B03_02"]/div[1]/a/@href').extract()[1:]
               for url in urls:
                    url1 = self.start_urls[0].split('/housing')[0] + url
                    yield scrapy.Request(url1, callback=self.parse0)    
          else:               
               url = self.start_urls[0]
               yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse1)


     def parse0(self, response): #http://esf.sh.fang.com/housing/25__1_0_0_0_1_0_0/
          num = response.xpath('//*[@id="pxBox"]/p/b/text()').extract()[0]
          if int(num) >2000:
               urls = response.xpath('//*[@id="shangQuancontain"]/a/@href').extract()[1:]
               for url in urls:
                    url2= self.start_urls[0].split('/housing')[0] + url
                    yield scrapy.Request(url2, callback=self.parse1)    
          else:
               #<Here,I want to get the URL address from url1 in function parse>
               yield scrapy.Request(url1,callback=self.parse1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always pass any data you want to your requests, and you can get them in callback methods.

```
yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, meta={"page":1})
```

And in parse method,

```
def parse(self, response):
    page = response.meta["page"] + 1
```

An alternative to your response.url

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
Using `url1 = response.url`

Comment: More details would be helpful to other users.